# Let [x] denote the greatest integer less than of equal to x. Let f(x) = x - [x]. Prove that if a is not set of integer then lim f(x) = a - [a].

Tags: limits, functions

I tried to start with let epsilon > 0 and |f(x) - l| for x - a < delta to prove that f(x) = a - [a].

|x - [x] - (a - [a])|

|x - [x] - a + [a]|

|x - a - [x] + [a]|

|delta - [x] + [a]| < epsilon

Where do I go from here? Or am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You are missing some characters, surely.  Do you mean for it to be $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)$ for instance?  Because $\lim f(x)$ by itself means nothing.  See [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for information on how to type with MathJax and $\LaTeX$ here.

Comment: Yes! I didn’t have enough of character to put that in question.